# Changing Flask app's config variables during app runtime?

Tags: python, sql, apache, flask

So I have a flask app running and this is how the config file looks like:

```
class config(object):
    SECRET_KEY = 'india'

class configTest(config):
   MYSQL_HOST = 'host1'
    MYSQL_PORT = 3306
    MYSQL_USER = 'admin'
    MYSQL_PASSWORD = 'yangmai'
    MYSQL_DB = 'ide'

class configProd(config):
    MYSQL_HOST = 'host2'
    MYSQL_PORT = 3306
    MYSQL_USER = 'admin'
    MYSQL_PASSWORD = 'yangmai'
    MYSQL_DB = 'ide'
```

In my init.py, I do this:

```
app.config.from_object('project.config.configTest')
```

Works good. Now what I want is to give user the option to switch the db at the time of logging in. So essentially, the config class should change from configTest to configProd or vice versa as the user selects.

The idea is to give user the option to access the test and prod environments without deploying two separate apps. Any solutions?
Also, the app is run by apache.

Comment: Are you using SQLAlchemy or Flask-SQLAlchemy ? Then the connection to the DB is made on app startup. If on the other hand you are handling the connection yourself then there is no problem, in fact you could have two connections open at the same time.

Comment: I am using Flask-Mysqldb. How do I define two connections in my config and then use them as per the case? Can you please share some hints on that?

Comment: Apparently it is possible to handle multiple connections with this package - see: [Flask-MySQL](https://flask-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). And if both databases are on the same host and the user has access rights to both of them, then you could prefix the tables with the database name.

Comment: My concern is there a way to change the config class in the init.py after the app is started? Both the dbs are identical in structure, the only difference being the data. I want to save myself from the hassle of using if statements for two connection requests.